# E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)

Tags: apt, permissions, dpkg

When I try to install a new app (a code editor in this case, brackets) I click on install but it doesn't work. When I want to install new updates available from Ubuntu Software it does this: I click on install, then it asks me for the admin password, I write it, the install bar gets full and stays like this for ever. No installation.

Please what could the problem be? I read other topics about this same problem but it doesn't seem to go away

Answer (score 0):

the file gets locked when a program tries to update, install, remove programs.  usually this just means another window is open which has something to do with updates, software etc, but can also be because the system itself has tried to automatically update at the same time.  waiting should fix; but won't if you've got a window/term open that is paused on an install/remove/update (eg. dpkg* configure/update)